# How to show (only) portions of Wireframe modifier? (Version 2.8)

Tags: modeling, animation, modifiers

I’ve modeled a group of rays emerging from a single point by using the Wireframe modifier, then cutting off the ring on the bottom via a Boolean Difference.

But how can I show just some of the rays, and hide others?  Trying to come up with an object for a Difference would be tricky, and not handle the common point well.  Plus I then want to *animate* that, showing one ray at a time to form the complete circle.

Any idea how to accomplish that?

[image: glowing rays]

Answer (score 2):

How about, instead of using the wireframe modifier:

- Deleting all but one of the radial edges of your cone, cut to the right length
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> convert it to a curve
- In the curve's data panel set its full bevel to your liking
- Make an empty at center of the cone (its original origin) rotated in Z by 360/32
- Make an array of your curve, count 32, Object Offset, the empty as target.

Now you can keyframe the visibility of the original curve (if you want a complete disappearance). For the rest, you can keyframe the Count of the Array modifier.

[image]